# Importing txt file into Postgres (delimiter problem?)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 700MB txt file that I want to import into my Postgres database.

However, I keep getting the error below. "Jurs" is the last column header.

Note that error happened on a line 10014, not line 1. So I believe I have created a proper schema for a new table but I noticed, on the Line 10014, there is a "\" next to BRUNSVILLE. Is that an issue? I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
db1=# \COPY harris_2018 FROM 'C:\Users\testu\Downloads\harris_2018\original\
Real_acct_owner\real_acct.txt' with DELIMITER E'\t';
```

> ERROR:  missing data for column "jurs"
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY harris_2018, line 10014: "0081300000008                  2018    STATE OF TEXAS  PO BOX 1386
>   HOUSTON TX      77251-1386              N               0                                ..."

Below is a txt file reader.
[image]

Comment: It's hard to say since we can't "See" tab characters which are acting as your delimiter. Can you pop that open in an editor where you can show whitespace characters and inspect the record to insure it has the proper number of fields? The error suggests that it's short a column. I can't imagine that the backslash would cause any issues here since it's a text file.

Comment: If you can run an awk command against this you could do `awk -F"\t" 'NR==1{fieldcount=NF}NR>1&&NF<>fieldcount{print NR, NF, "Expected "fieldcount, $0}' yourfile` and it will spit out any lines that aren't the same number of columns as the first record in the file. That can be very revealing with these kinds of ETL issues.